# Determining the matrix representations of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry, mobius-transformation

Show that each function\begin{align}f(x)=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}, g(x)=\dfrac{ex+f}{jx+h}\end{align}
can be represented by matrices such that the matrix representation of the composition $g(f(x))$ is the product of the matrices of $g$ and $f$.

I tried expressing $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ to $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{bc-da}{c(cx+d)}=ac^2x+bc+cda-da$. Which made me think might $x$ be a constant, vector, etc...? I would like to as for hints on this.

Comment: In a complex variable these are known as mobius transformations in protective geometry. Try searching with terms like "Mobius transformation" AND "Matrix representation" etc.

Comment: I'm currently studying linear algebra and this problem appeared on non-singular matrices. This seems to be an advance topic; how did this get into the textbook I'm using. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: There's one and only one matrix that comes to mind as representing ${ax+b\over cx+d}$.

Comment: I don't think Möbius transformations are part of linear algebra, even though they can be represented by matrices. The way Möbius transformations are represented by matrices is different from the way linear transformations are represented by matrices.

Comment: Does the function $f$ have domain being $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$?

Comment: my book didn't state. besides $a,b,c,d,e,f,j,h\in \Bbb{F}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know some group theory up to the first isomorphism theorem to understand the matrix representation.

The map from $\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb F)$ to the group of all Möbius transformations, sending $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ to the Möbius transformation $f$, where $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, is a surjective group homomorphism, with the kernel of this map being $\{I,-I\}$. So by the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb F)/\{I,-I\}\cong$ Möbius transformation group. The induced isomorphism tells us that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\{I,-I\}$ represents the function $f$. But we may drop $\{I,-I\}$ and simply say that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ represents $f$.

For details about the above claims with proofs, consult Alan Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry*, the chapter on Möbius transformations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the book reference, it looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try evaluating $g(f(x))$.

By the way, in general it is not true that
$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{bc-da}{c(cx+d)} = ac^2 x + bc + cda - da.$$

As hinted in the comments by Ethan, try searching for [Möbius Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Comment: and is there anyway, I could derive this matrix using only elementary linear algebra concepts?

Comment: To answer your other comment, the natural matrix representation for the function
$$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
is
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I found the matrix by referencing the wiki on mobius transformations, but as to why it is the matrix representation seems to me to be still out of the coverage of elementary linear algebra.

Comment: Again, my hint is that you try to write out the composition $g(f(x))$ explicitly.

Comment: I already have and I understand the mechanical part of deriving it. All I'm saying is I don't see a connection between the mechanical process and the theory of why that is.